# uWSGI listen queue of socket full

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

My setup includes Load Balancer (haproxy) with two nginx servers running Django. Server 2 works fine but sometimes server 1 will start crashing and log will be full of

```
*** uWSGI listen queue of socket ":8000" (fd: 3) full !!! (101/100) ***
```

message.

How do I go about resolving this issue?

Comment: This is great, but you need to ask a question.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I thought question was quite clear. How do i resolve this issue? What might be the problem?

Comment: https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/1369

Comment: The [listen queue](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/articles/TheArtOfGracefulReloading.html#the-listen-queue) section of uWSGI docs explains the problem and suggest increasing `net.core.somaxconn`.

Answer (score 11):

Your listen queue is full. When you run uwsgi, pass it `--listen 1024` to increase the queue to 1024.

Note that a larger queue makes you more susceptible to a DDoS attack.

You may also need to increase `net.core.somaxconn`

```
sysctl -w net.core.somaxconn=65536
```

Comment: Any advice for this error, except it's in a local Docker container that just started up and the overflow shows `(376207488/1)` ?

Comment: You can increase listen queue in uwsgi.ini file added a new line, example:

```listen = 1024```

Answer (score 5):

Actually, increasing queue size does not make much sense since while requests are lying in the uWSGI queue, they are not processed by workers and response time is growing. To fix the symptom with a uWSGI queue overflowing you need vertical or horizontal scaling (if it can be done with your infrastructure) of your application.

Answer (score 0):

*I was having the same issue, I Hope It may help someone.*

After a small headache, I figured out that in my case the thumbnails are causing the issue (i.e. static files). My website is big and the `easy-thumbnails` had created so many duplicate files in the static folder.

To solve the issue I have used [this module/app](https://github.com/akolpakov/django-unused-media).

Now I just ran `manage.py cleanup_unused_media` command and all unwanted files got deleted (there were 18k files in my case). Now the app is running smoothly.

**Make sure NGINX/Apache is serving your static files in production.**